# The receiving account ether's does not increase whilst the sender ether's decrease

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, metamask, smart-contract-wallets

I got that function that sends contributions to the smart contract as i thought
everything works perfectly when the sender uses it to send contributions
his account balance decreases and that line is invoked without any problems `Campaigns[campaignIndex].currentAmount += msg.value;`

but the effect of that line `payable(Campaigns[campaignIndex].creatorsAddress).transfer(msg.value);` that sends the contributions back to the campaign's creator's address is not working -> his balance does not increase
also i made the creator's address (address payable) but the problem persists

```
function contribute(uint256 campaignIndex) public payable {

    Campaigns[campaignIndex].currentAmount += msg.value;

    // Transfer the contributed funds to the campaign creator
    payable(Campaigns[campaignIndex].creatorsAddress).transfer(msg.value);

}
```

i am using ganache accounts in a manually created localhost network in metamask

Comment: Code is working file in Remix local

Comment: yes it works fine in remix